# Gnome Shell Issue: Xorg Crashes, GDM3 Restarts Several TImes Per Dasy

Tags: kali-linux, gnome, xorg

I recently updated my Kali/Debian system with apt and then ever since, Xorg has been crashing which causes GDM3 to reboot. This happens several times per day. I have tried:

- Reinstalling Gnome Shell
- Reconfiguring Gnome-Shell via dpkg
- Deleting my local x configurations
- Resetting all gnome settings
- Booting from previous kernel

No matter what I do, eventually Xorg crashes which causes GDM3 to restart, going to the login screen. It is really, really annoying. There is nothing in the system logs to provide any clue.

If I can't figure it out soon, I am just going to nuke this system and switch back to a standard Debian/Gnome release. I am running GNOME Shell 43.1, and this is a laptop system with an Intel processor.

If anyone can help me figure out what is happening and fix this, that would be ideal. I don't want to have to reinstall.

**EDIT**: Okay, thanks to @NikitaKipriyanov
, I managed to locate the log, and I got a stack trace which I am going to link here because it's too long: https://termbin.com/de9k8

I also have a coredump. I was going to post that on gnome forums but am trying to avoid it because i am not sure how to ensure there's no sensitive data in it.

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/Xorg.*.log`?

Comment: Nothing obvious, not sure if I can increase the verbosity? Here are the last 50 entries in /var/log/Xorg* before the x server dies, not sure if this is useful at all or not: https://termbin.com/dc5f

Comment: `[ 82410.700] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.` — that means not the X server crashed, but the session manager. Check `dmesg` for any segfaults or the like. Also I was not aware that [.xsession-errors is deprecated](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-debug.html.en). Please do as they suggest.

Comment: Oh man, thank you! Okay I am will edit question and add the crash log now!